# Shopify analytics, Google analytics, Meta pixel, and Lighthouse page speed

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, google-tag-manager, lighthouse, facebook-pixel

While I was trying to improve on the Chrome Lighthouse metrics, I've noticed at the top of my list the "Unused JavaScript" section.

I have been able to resolve most of the issues, however I'm stuck at the analytics scripts.

There is a piece of code coming from shopify's mandatory `{{ content_for_header }}`. In older answers, I've seen people using `{{ content_for_header | replace: ... }}` to improve the performance metrics, but Shopify's engine doesn't allow changes to `{{ content_for_header }}` anymore.

From this `{{ content_for_header }}`, I've noticed a library called `trekkie`, and the method that seems to be loading the scripts that impact performance:

```
trekkie.load(
      {"Trekkie":{"appName":"storefront","development":false,"defaultAttributes":{"shopId":70687719722,"isMerchantRequest":true,"themeId":151814897962,"themeCityHash":"14783982111867270093","contentLanguage":"en","currency":"EUR"},"isServerSideCookieWritingEnabled":true,"monorailRegion":"shop_domain"},"Facebook Pixel":{"pixelIds":["1385989091411151"],"agent":"plshopify1.2"},"Google Gtag Pixel":{"conversionId":"AW-11255878899","eventLabels":[{"type":"begin_checkout","action_label":"AW-11255878899\/gxIVCNbTrLkYEPOpnPcp"},{"type":"search","action_label":"AW-11255878899\/C5mzCNDTrLkYEPOpnPcp"},{"type":"view_item","action_label":["AW-11255878899\/9M3CCM3TrLkYEPOpnPcp","MC-0RLQZ0B8H3"]},{"type":"purchase","action_label":["AW-11255878899\/Ru6NCM_SrLkYEPOpnPcp","MC-0RLQZ0B8H3"]},{"type":"page_view","action_label":["AW-11255878899\/WO6tCMrTrLkYEPOpnPcp","MC-0RLQZ0B8H3"]},{"type":"add_payment_info","action_label":"AW-11255878899\/RROtCNnTrLkYEPOpnPcp"},{"type":"add_to_cart","action_label":"AW-11255878899\/Y9k7CNPTrLkYEPOpnPcp"}],"targetCountry":"US"},"Session Attribution":{},"S2S":{"facebookCapiEnabled":true,"facebookAppPixelId":"1385989091411151","source":"trekkie-storefront-renderer"}}
    );
```

I'm trying to understand how I should load all the three different pixels: Shopify, Google, Meta.

1. Is it possible to collect the data with just one of them, and then share the data between all three platforms?
2. Also, if I remove all my Google and Meta tags, I still see `trekkie` loading its Google Tag. Does this mean Shopify uses Google Tag for its analytics?
3. Google Tag Managers sounds like it can accomodate different tags. Is it something I should configure instead of confguring Shopify, if my goal is to use the analytics mainly for feeding the ads algorithms?

[image]

Comment: The answer is not straighforward so I'll just leave a comment. 1,3) Yes, you should use GTM. 2) You can't remove trekkie but if you configure Shopify properly (using GTM as well) you can limit its importance. Also check Shopify Customer Events